# Retrieving a List of Contacts android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contacts, android-loader

I want to display the Contact List using Fragment. The number will show on toast when the user selects names from the list.The list will show only name.How can I get the numbers form contact. I went through the android developer training for retrieving a contact list, but the tutorial is incomplete and even downloading the sample code doesn't help because the sample code is for more advanced contact list manipulation (search, etc.)

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Context context = getActivity();
    int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    Cursor c = null; // there is no cursor yet
    int flags = 0; // no auto-requery! Loader requeries.       

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, FROM, TO, flags);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
       {               
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Clicked!"
                   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }        
    }); 
    // each time we are started use our listadapter
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    // and tell loader manager to start loading
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final String SELECTION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?" : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";

private String mSearchString;
private String[] mSelectionArgs = { mSearchString };

private static final String[] PROJECTION =
{
        Contacts._ID,
        Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
  };

private static final String[] FROM = { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
private static final int[] TO = { android.R.id.text1 };
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) 
{

    Uri contentUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) 
{

    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) 
{

    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the numbers form contact

I'd start with editing your `PROJECTION` array and adding [HAS_PHONE_NUMBER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#HAS_PHONE_NUMBER) column to not proceed if there's no phone number associated.

If there's is, then using your contact's ID you can do something like this (note the type constrain, so edit according to your needs):

```
Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver()
                     .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[]{ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,
                     new String[]{ contactId },
                     null);

if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
    contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone
           .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
}

cursorPhone.close();
```